# How to execute a method before an interrupt

Tags: ruby, interrupt

Is there a way when writing a Ruby script to specify a command to be executed before the script stops due to a keyboard interrupt like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it in the [Ruby documentation for `Interrupt`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Interrupt.html), for those who are interested

```
begin
  puts "Press ctrl-C when you get bored"
  loop {}
rescue Interrupt => e
  puts "Note: You will typically use Signal.trap instead."
end
```